# How can I apply one or more attributes to all classes in a project?

Tags: c#, attributes, class-attributes, cls-compliant, class-attribute

How can I apply an attribute to all classes in a particular project?!
And is it enough to apply CLSCompliant attribute to just one class or do I have to apply to all classes?

Thanks for your answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the declaration for the attribute:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class CLSCompliantAttribute : Attribute
```

Note the [AttributeUsage].  With AttributeTargets.All, it indicates that the attribute can be applied to anything.  Which includes the assembly:

```
[assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]
```

Answer (score 2):

A project is an assembly, so you could use an [assembly attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s.aspx).